# UIImagePickerController event handling

Tags: ios, swift, events, uiimagepickercontroller

Using a `UIImagePickerController` in an iOS app (in Swift), I have the following issue.

There is a method fired when an image has been selected and chosen:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
```

But between the time the `UIImagePickerController` list appears on the display and the time an image is selected and chosen, many things happen.
Looking at the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol, it seems we have very little control on the situation.

What about the event where the user taps an item in the list? Is there any method(like didSelectRowAtIndexPath) being fired where I can do something?

Same when the view with the selected image appears. Is there any thing I can do?

Comment: I don't see a problem or a question here.

Comment: One question is: How can I do something when the user taps an item in the list? (Is there a method called when it happens?)

Answer (score -1):

Given your follow-up question, the answer is yes as long as you provide supplemental custom overlay to the picker. Here's the relevant passage in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html):

> You can customize an image picker controller to manage user
> interactions yourself. To do this, provide an overlay view containing
> the controls you want to display, and use the methods described in
> Capturing Still Images or Movies. You can display your custom overlay
> view in addition to, or instead of, the default controls. Custom
> overlay views for the UIImagePickerController class are available in
> iOS 3.1 and later by way of the cameraOverlayView property. For a code
> example, see the Using UIImagePickerController to Select Pictures and
> Take Photos sample code project.

If you have a specific question regarding implementing one of these methods (which the referenced sample project should help with), please ask a new question.

Comment: I just had a quick look, I don't want to take pictures, just browse the list, and possibly select something. It seems somewhat a bit involved for what I need.